# Disabling Swapping of a Redis Instance on AWS's ElastiCache

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

We are trying to disable swapping RAM to the disk for a Redis instance managed by AWS's Elasticache - but couldn't find the right property to do so.

We also cannot find a way to SSH it and turn off swapping from the kernerl, can you please help ?

Comment: You can't do it with Elasticache.

Comment: @DuruCanCelasun: Can you please point the OP to a useful link?
Also - are you aware of alternative ways of reducing swapping?

Comment: @EyalSchneider I'd love to do that, but it's not really documented, it's one of those things you just know. Redis does not directly control swapping, so the only way to change swap behaviour is with using `sysctl` to modify `proc.sys.vm.swappiness`, which is not possible with a managed service like Elasticache. For OP, I recommend either scaling up to a larger instance, or using EC2 to host Redis yourself.

Comment: @DuruCanCelasun what about enabling Redis's Latency Monitoring framework ? Is it possible to turn it on while using ElastiCache ?

Answer (score 1):

While not a direct answer to your question about disabling swapping, we've been struggling with Redis swaping on Elasticache as well.  What we ended up doing to address swapping is the following:

- Followed Leo's suggestion of setting reserved memory
- Run a nightly batch job to SCAN all keys in batches of 10,000.  The SCAN command will evict any expired keys. This helps by proactively cleaning up the cache before swapping kicks in.
- Run another custom batch job which processes entities we know can be evicted. These are entities which aren't as important as others which are in the cache. We've setup the keys so they contain enough information to easily identify those associated to an entity. Use SCAN with a match to find the keys.  Once you find them, call DEL on each.  This batch job alone is saving lots of space in our Redis instance.  Word of caution, avoid using the KEYS command as it is slow and will block other threads.

We've been using the above for a few weeks now and so far it has been working well.  In a few more weeks we'll know how well it works since we have a default TTL of 30 days and the number of cached items is still increasing.

Good luck!

**Update**

We turned off the job which uses SCAN on all keys. We discovered it was causing swap to slowly creep up (roughly 500k every other day). Once we turned that off, swap started shrinking. The combination of setting reserved memory and flushing objects we know can be expired is working well. When redis starts running out of room, it evicts any expired cached objects to make room for new entries. The only impact we've noticed is a very small increase in CPU usage, which isn't causing any trouble.

Comment: You could also set the maxmemory-policy to volatile-lru to automatically evict keys, that have TTL, when you are out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, where Elasticache(Redis) in AWS suddenly started using Swap space even while we use the Allkeys-LRU algorithm. The machine was not using swap while consuming the whole memory for the past few weeks until that changed one early morning.

I used the command

```
redis-cli -h elasticache.service-name memory DOCTOR
```

The output was -->

> - High allocator fragmentation: This instance has an allocator external fragmentation greater than 1.1. This problem is usually due
>     either to a large peak memory (check if there is a peak memory entry
>     above in the report) or may result from a workload that causes the
>     allocator to fragment memory a lot. You can try enabling
>     'activedefrag' config option.

checking with command

```
redis-cli -h elasticache.service-name memory STATS
```

I saw that the defragment value was high(1.4)

I looked onto the AWS console for Elasticache-Redis params and made the defragment setting to true as it was set as false.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to connect to Elasticache via SSH.

Are you sure that you are having issues with Redis swapping to disk, or the host running out of memory and crashing (I've seen this happen with the default configuration)? If so, the guidance is to leave about 25% of the system memory available for host processes - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/redis-memory-management.html